# fix memory leaks with valgrind

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am working with c++ and been using valgrind to fix memory leaks.
I am trying to optimize the following piece of code that valgrind characterizes as a leak:

```
void VOMC::sub_train(vector<Letter> tempLettersA, vector<Letter> tempLettersB) {
    int stateA_id = state_exists(tempLettersA);
    State *tempStateA;

    if (stateA_id != -1) {
        tempStateA = get_state_by_id(stateA_id);
    } else {
        tempStateA = new State(tempLettersA);// MEMORY LEAK - 1
        vomc.push_back(tempStateA);
    }
    int stateB_id = state_exists(tempLettersB);
    if (stateB_id != -1) {
        tempStateA->inc_state(stateB_id);
    } else {
        State* tempStateB;
        tempStateB = new State(tempLettersB);//MEMORY LEAK -2
        vomc.push_back(tempStateB);
        stateB_id = tempStateB->GetId();
        tempStateA->inc_state(stateB_id);
    }
}
```

For memory leak-1 I get the following message

```
==11289== 4,055 (64 direct, 3,991 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in   loss record 228 of 228
==11289==    at 0x402B87E: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
==11289==    by 0x807FA75: VOMC::sub_train(std::vector<Letter, std::allocator<Letter> >,    std::vector<Letter, std::allocator<Letter> >) (VOMC.cpp:952)
```

For memory leak -2

```
==11289==    at 0x402B87E: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:292)
==11289==    by 0x807FB16: VOMC::sub_train(std::vector<Letter, std::allocator<Letter> >,     std::vector<Letter, std::allocator<Letter> >) (VOMC.cpp:968)
```

Can I delete these pointers? This would remove my leaks BUT as you can see the pointers are being pushed into a stack, the goal is to maintain them in the stack but remove the leak.

EDIT -1 : adding letter and state definitinons:

```
class Letter {

public:
    Letter();
    Letter(Helper *helper);
    ~Letter();

    void add_note(RawNote r);
    void evaluate_letter(double eigthNoteDuration);
    void setNotePositionAccordingToLetter();
    void empty_notes();
    LetterPattern getPattern() const;
    void setPattern(LetterPattern pattern);
    bool isEmpty();
    vector<RawNote> getRawNotes() const;
    void setRawNotes(vector<RawNote> rawNotes);

    bool has_note_no_velocity(RawNote* r1);
    bool has_note_with_velocity(RawNote* r1);

private:
    vector<LetterPattern> *allPossibleNotes;
    vector<RawNote> rawNotes;
    LetterPattern pattern;
```

};

```
class State {
public:
State(); //should not be used, it is only for testing
State(vector<Letter> letters);
virtual ~State();
int GetId() const;
void SetId(int id);
vector<Letter> GetLetters() const;
void SetLetters(vector<Letter> letters);
void AddLetters(vector<Letter> letters);
void inc_state(int state_id);
void print_state_letters();
bool has_state(int state_id);
void print_connected_states();
void print_sorted_states();
vector<string> get_rhythm_as_string();
map<int, double> GetConnected_states() const;
map<int, double> connected_states;
vector< pair <int, double > > vector_sorted_connected_states;
void bubblesort_vector_descending(vector< pair <int, double > > *v_sort);
int get_connected_state_stochastically();
static int id_generator;
CustomNumberDist *normal_dist;
int id_from_file; //only used on load of a file
private:
int id;
vector<Letter> letters;
};
```

Comment: Do yourself a favour and change pointers to smart pointers. I recommend `shared_ptr` in `<memory>`.

Comment: You will have to `delete[]` them *sometimes*, otherwise they are leaked. We don't know what you do in the rest of the program, or why you have to store pointers in vomc, so it's hard to advice.

Comment: The idea is that I use this pointers later on so I can not delete them. I'll take a look at your suggestion @stefan thanks

Comment: @PotneySwitters: It's really easy. Just do `std::shared_ptr<State> myPointer = std::make_shared<State>(tempLettersA);`

Comment: @stefan wait, how do you know the ownership is shared? Did I miss something? Do you have information that is not on the post? @Potney do yourself a favour and... consider not using pointers of any level of smartness first, then `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I don't. But if in doubt, shared_ptr can't really go wrong, can it?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes "A const std::unique_ptr cannot be transferred, limiting the lifetime of the managed object to the scope in which the pointer was created. When the unique_ptr is destroyed, it disposes of the object through Deleter." This tells me that the pointer will be deleted when leaving this function. The whole idea is to use it outside the function, that'why it is being pushed back in the vomc vector. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @PotneySwitters Erm, why would you want to make it const, then?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I don't want to make the pointer a const. I just want it not to be destroyed outside this function. From the definition mentioned before it seems that the memory is freed when exiting the function. If this happens it cancels the whole idea of the function.

Comment: @PotneySwitters No, that's not true. The object is destroyed when the pointer that owns it is destroyed. Unless you make it const (and thus non-transferrable) you can transfer the ownership into the stack, and then it is destroyed when the stack is destroyed.

Comment: Without the definition of `Letter` and `State`, and the relationship between the two since it seems that: 1/ `Letter(State*)` exists and 2/ `State(std::vector<Letter>)` exists, it's hard to know what you are trying to do and therefore give any specific advise. Apart that, maybe, you are using `new` too much and should just allocate on the stack ?

Comment: Well I have not read anything on new being of too much usage. Is there a problem with it? Actually, I am trying to dig up this details on memory management which are unclear to me and give me leaks

Comment: @PotneySwitters: The main reason to use `new` is to fully control the lifetime of an object, and thus go beyond the "birth at the declaration site and death at the end of the scope" lifetime that stack-allocated objects get. If stack allocation is good enough, then don't use `new` and you'll have no memory leaks ;) May we get to see the definitions of `Letter` and `State` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that valgrind can tell you is the source of the leak. It can't tell you where the missing invocation to `delete` is -- it's missing.

One solution is to delete pointers after popping them off the stack and have the `VOMC::~VOMC()` delete all elements that remain on the stack. This approach works only if the class `VOMC` "owns" each and every of the objects on the stack. This approach can't work if the stack also contains pointers to `State` objects that are somehow owned by some other object.

Dealing with mixed ownership is a bit tough with containers of raw pointers. One way to deal with a container of raw pointers in which ownership is mixed is to add an `owned_by` pointer to the class `State` (or whatever is being contained). Now your class `VOMC` only deletes those objects that are owned by `this`. There's a architectural issue here: It reeks of code smell. An analog to this approach exists in SWIG, where you sometimes need to set the  `thisown` property to false. My code smell sensor goes off scale high when I see stuff like that.

A third approach is to just get rid of those raw pointers. Instead of a collection of raw pointers, make your `vomc` data member a collection of objects (not pointers) that are instances of some kind of smart pointer. This is the modern approach to dealing with raw pointers, which is not to use raw pointers.